# question about a proof of uniform boundedness principle

Tags: functional-analysis

In reading [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/273009/745350) I didn't understand this step:
[image]
$\hskip97mm\color{red}{\overline{\strut\hskip4cm}}$
I know that $\| x-x_n \| ≤\sum_{i=n+1}^{∞} 3^{-i}=\frac{1}{2} 3^{-n}$
But I do not see how it implies  $\| T_n x \| ≥ \frac{1}{6} 3^{-n}\|T_n\|$
Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: O, I see.

$\|T_nx\|\ge\|T_nx_n\|-\|T_n(x-x_n)\|\ge(\frac23-\frac12)3^{-n}\|T_n\|$

Comment: The question is automatically closed. Do I need to do something?